# Session sharing issue

Tags: http, web-applications, session

I am facing an issue when we are using multiple tabs since its sharing the same session. Any alternatives to this? Can we create a unique session when someone uses the tab or CTRL+N.

It's a Java EE/Struts2 enterprise application if this matters.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem all server-centric web applications face, it's not specific to Java EE. The problem is that most browsers store cookies on a per-user basis, not per tab. Also, this behaviour is not generally transparent to the user, adding to the confusion. A few solutions I can think of (although none of them is really satisfactory):

- Host the application under more than one URI. This way, any browser will store cookies independently, and consequently, you have one session per application version.
- Propagate session IDs through a different mechanism, e.g. through the URI. This, however, has a few caveats - it exposes the session ID to the user, it makes for ugly URIs, and it forms a security risk (session hijacking and such) when users copy-paste or bookmark the current URI (because they then store the session ID in the link).
- Propagate session IDs through hidden fields inside the page. This solution probably requires you to rewrite part of the built-in session handling, and it loses the session ID when your page contains links to other pages within your application.
- For Firefox, there's an add-on called "cookie pie", which allows users to have independent cookie stores for some or all tabs. Downside is that users have to actively enable it, and working around the tab problem becomes the user's responsibility. Also, it doesn't work under all circumstances (e.g., google finds your active login regardless).
- Avoid using session state, and use other mechanisms to preserve state between requests. Like passing session IDs through hidden fields, this breaks under certain circumstances.
- Make the application fully client-centric, that is, program the entire interface in javascript and communicate with the server through ajax calls. This way, you won't depend on the browser's cookie implementation at all. Chances are you'll have to rewrite substantial amounts of code though, assuming your application is basically working already.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to achieve this that I know of.

The usual way to fix this is to change the app so that it can deal with users using multiple tabs (if possible).

There are several workaround ideas for how to "disable" the old window if the user presses Ctrl+N while walking through a multi-step form, but you'd have to give more detailed information for ideas on that.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a browser instance is treated as a single user/entity for session tracking purposes. Especially if you are using cookies to track the sessions. I am not sure that I like the idea of allowing different tabs to have different sessions. It feels unintuitive for web based applications. All IMHO, of course.

That said, if you want to change this you will have to come up with a custom implementation. Perhaps you can generate and attach different session ids to the URL for different tabs. Never tried this myself so do not know how easy or difficult it will be.